# Функция animate scroll top зацикливается (зависает)

Tags: javascript, jquery

При прокрутке страницы, когда определённый объект, в данном случае, `registration-form`, достигает по вертикали координату меньше 0, должен происходить `scroll-top`.

Все происходит шикарно, казалось, что дело в шляпе, но функция почему-то скроллит, а потом что-то на подобии зацикливания происходит. То есть, если ещё раз попытаться проскроллить, то контент как будто прилип к нулевой отметке по `y` и начинает дрожать и дёргаться, то и дело возвращаясь на 0 не проскроллив и 20 пикселей. А через несколько секунд если ничего не делать, то все становиться снова как нужно.

В чем проблема?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var form = document.getElementById("registration-form").getBoundingClientRect();


    if (form.top < 0) {

      $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
      }, 700);
      return false;
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо обозначать «состояние» – либо свободный скролл, либо откат на 0. Во время отката перестать слушать события скролла. С флагом примерно так попробуйте:

```js
var form = document.getElementById("registration-form");
var freeScroll = true; // флаг

function _scroll() {
  if( !freeScroll) return;  
  if (form.getBoundingClientRect().top < 0) {
    freeScroll = false;
    $("html, body").animate(
      {scrollTop: 0, queue: false},
      700,
      function() { freeScroll = true;}
    );
  }
}

$(window).on('scroll', _scroll);
```

[Рабочий пример](https://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/jvaqvc6o/).

Comment: Попробовал вот так  - не сработало. $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0 , queue: false }, 700);

Comment: Значит, надо флаг выставлять: обозначать «состояние» – либо свободный скролл, либо откат на 0. Во время отката перестать слушать события скролла.

Comment: К сожалению этот вариант не работает. При скролле функция вызывается, но действий никаких не делает.

Comment: Потому, что переменной form надо дать значением элемент. А внутри события scroll вызывать метод getBoundingClientRect() этого элемента. Обновил код и добавил рабочий пример

Comment: Спасибо за работающий пример. Буду знать.